# Update code on production env where we have live users all time

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, production-environment

Our app is in **prod mode** now.

**How can I update the server code?**

Issue: It might have a chance that someone is accessing a server or doing some CRUD.
It may impact the data and we have some payment-related things as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonably easy and straight-forward way is a [blue-green deployment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-green_deployment). (Unlike what the Wikipedia article says, the instances don't need to be physical servers, just app instance listening on multiple ports on the same server, for instance.
)

Assuming you'd be upgrading from version 1 to version 2:

- Your frontend load balancer (e.g. ELB) directs traffic to version 1.
- You deploy version 2.
- You configure ELB to start directing traffic to version 2 and stop directing to version 1.
- Once there is no traffic to version 1, you shut it down.

Extra care must of course be taken if version 2 involves e.g. database schema changes that aren't compatible with version 1.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have the same solution in my mind but I don't know how to do it.